# Changing output values in a dictionary from strings to floats and/or integers in Python

Tags: python

So far I have this code:

```
def read_file(filename):

    with open("menu1.csv") as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line_strip = [line.rstrip('\n')]
            lines= [line.split(',')]
            result = {key: tuple(val) for key, *val in lines}
            print(result)
```

and i get the following output:

```
{'Chic-fil-A Chicken Sandwich': ('3.75', '440', 'Entrees\n')}

{'Chic-fil-A Deluxe Sandwich': ('4.45', '500', 'Entrees\n')}

{'Spicy Chicken Sandwich': ('3.99', '460', 'Entrees\n')}

{'Spicy Deluxe Sandwich': ('4.69', '550', 'Entrees\n')}

{'Grilled Chicken Sandwich': ('5.15', '320', 'Entrees\n')}

{'Grilled Chicken Club': ('6.55', '460', 'Entrees\n')}
```

The output continues but that is just a part of it. I need to make the first number in the  () a float, and the second one an integer. For example, for the first output listed, I need the '3.75' to be a float 3.75 and the '440' to be an integer 440.

ALSO how do i make the '\n' not show up in the output?? I need the output to stay stacked on top of each other like it is. But without the '\n' showing up with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can directly do this while constructing the dictionary:

```
def read_file(filename):

    with open("menu1.csv") as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line_strip = [line.rstrip('\n')]
            lines= [line.split(',')]
            result = {key: (float(fl), int(intg), text.strip()) 
                            for key, fl, intg, text in lines}
            print(result)
```

This may work (considering I did not make any mistake) as a shorter version (not sure how short it actually is :P):

```
def read_file(filename):

    with open("menu1.csv") as file:
        result = {key: (float(fl), int(intg), text.strip())
                        for line in file 
                        for key, fl, intg, text in [line.strip().split(',')]}
        print(result)
```